# Accessing the webapplication with domain instead of localhost/ipaddress gives WebPage not found?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, web-applications, dns

i have my java webapplication deployed on tomcat. I am able to access it with

```
https://localhost:8443/myWebAp
```

But i want access it  with some  domain name instead of localhost. For this i make an below entry in hosts file at   C:/Windows/System32/drivers/etc/hosts

```
       10.215.134.45   shopCart.myApp.com
```

Now i access my application with url

```
       https://shopCart.myApp.com:8443/myWebAp
```

it says webpage can not be found. Though as soon as i enter my ip i.e 10.215.134.45  instead of shopCart.myApp.com it works fine. Another weird thing is if i give entry as

```
  10.215.134.45   shopCart
```

and now acceess the app with

```
 https://shopCart:8443/myWebAp
```

it works fine but as soon as i append some .(dot) with shopCart, looks  like it browser is not able to resolve ip against shopCart.myApp.com. I am not getting whats the reason behind it?I also tried giving 127.0.0.1  instead of my ip against domain name but same result

Comment: Are you behind a proxy of some sort? Also, what browser are you using, and how is your proxy configured? This generally happens only if the browser is using your proxy to resolve the URL rather than using your hosts file/DNS.

Comment: Thanks Rajesh. You should post it as answer. I had settings as Auto detect proxy in my browser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This generally happens only if you are behind a proxy, and the browser is using your proxy to resolve the URL rather than using your hosts file/DNS. You should add *.myApp.com to the proxy exceptions list, to ensure that it resolves the IP address for the domain using your hosts file.